# aiogram Как открыть файл построчно без лишних символов

Tags: python, aiogram

Файл открывается и пишется ботом с лишними символами и без переноса строки. Как убрать лишние символы и добавить перенос строки т.е. хочу что бы было точно также как и в файле? Например я пишу в txt файле

```
Hello 
world
```

А в телеграм отпровляется

```
['Hello', 'world']
```

Код я использую такой

```
 with open('media/test.txt') as f:
 failik = [line.rstrip() for line in f] 

@dp.message_handler(commands=['test'])
async def process_start_command(message: types.Message):
    await message.reply(failik)
```

Как исправить

Comment: await message.reply(failik[0] + "\n" + failik[1])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что `[line.rstrip() for line in f]`  читает файл построчно и для каждой строки добавляет один элемент в список. Потом в `reply` вы передаете не строку, а список, а `reply` умеет посылать только строки. По-этому, он вначале список конвертирует в строку. Отсюда появляются открывающая и закрывающие скобки, запятыем между элементами и кавычки.

Читайте все содержимое файла сразу как одну строку (а не построчно) и ее и передавайте в `reply`:

```
with open('media/test.txt') as f:
 failik = f.read()
```